# Meet integrado en c#

Tags: c#, api

Buen dia.
Alguien tiene conocimiento sobre como **integrar Meet** en una aplicacion c# (La idea es poder realizar una videoconferencia dentro de una aplicacion), si se requiere alguna API, de antemano les agradezco el apoyo.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.